# What type of mathematical structure is a physicist's definition of a vector space?

Tags: vectors, definition

A [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) as defined by a mathematician lacks the invariant scalar product that lies at the heart of what I would define as a physicist's definition of a vector space that models the physical world. What type of mathematical structure is a physicist's definition of a vector space?

So far, I've managed to find the [inner product space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) which lacks the additional invariant property I'm looking for.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @garyp it's in the title.

Comment: What invariant property does the inner product space not have?  Your question still isn't clear to me.  Maybe I'm dense.

Comment: @garyp He may be thinking of the invariance of distances under Galilean boosts and Lorentz scalars under Lorentz boosts. Certainly those are the only examples that occur to me, but I think that a plain old inner-product space has those.

Comment: @garyp the transformation of an inner product space under rotations and translations, leaving the inner product invariant.

Comment: Leaving the inner product invariant?  If we had to leave the inner product invariant, we wouldn't be able to do general relativity!

Comment: GR is based on a manifold, not a vector space.  The tangent space at each point of that GR manifold is in fact a Minkowski space.

Comment: Fair enough, but even restricting ourselves to flat Minkowski spaces, coordinate transformations are not restricted to keeping the inner product invariant, but we recognize that those transformations do not alter the physical spacetime in any meaningful way.

Comment: @dmckee has it:  the inner product/quadratic form/scalar product implies invariance under rotations.  I'd leave out translations, as that brings in the additional structure of the underlying manifold.  A vector space is always "pegged at the origin", so to speak.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77554/

Comment: @Muphrid That's why I suggested that "invariant" doesn't mean anything, it comes for free.  The O.P. seems to be clearly thinking of the orthogonal group, but it comes for free.

Comment: I have never seen the rotation free transformations called "boosts" before. Too old perhaps. I have not found the etymology after some searching, though it sounds like something V.I. Arnold would think up, or jargon from inertial navigation. Anyone know where it started or was popularized? (If it is in MTW or Ohanian (old edition) or Weinberg, I promise I'll facepalm)

Comment: This seems to be asking more or less the same thing as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789956/whats-the-term-for-a-physical-vector-space) I posted on [math.SE].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Physicists use three vector spaces: Euclidean space, Minkowski space, and a separable Hilbert space (with some exceptions).   All of these have a quadratic form (in the first and third, it is an inner product, but it is not positive definite for Minkowski space) allowing one to define angles.  (Okay, for the Hilbert space, it is twisted by the complex conjugation, but you get the idea.)

But what does "invariant" mean? Really, it doesn't mean anything because given the quadratic form, then one defines the group $O$ (or, in the complex case, $U$) as the linear transformations of the space that are invertible and continuous and preserve the quadratic (or Hermitian, as the case may be) form.  So "invariant" means nothing, it comes for free.  Given any form, one can find a group that preserves it, and then it is invariant under that group.

========             ==============

Much of theoretical physics is *linear*.  Some is not.  Only when it is linear can one use nothing but vector spaces.  Vector spaces are inherently linear.  When the phenomena are non-linear, then linear forms (and a quadratic form is really a kind of bi-linear form) become less useful, and have, at any rate, to be supplemented with other, more difficult, constructs.  Like flows and foliations etc.

GR is non-linear, and uses curved manifolds, which are not vector spaces.  Even then they are locally like vector spaces, and so linear analysis plays an important part of it, and the vector spaces appear as the tangent spaces to a curved manifold.  But that was not the original question.

Comment: What about tangent spaces on curved manifolds or the space of $p$-forms (as in: we use more than the three vector spaces you refer to)?

Comment: Those are Euclidean spaces, or, in the case of relativity, Minkowski spaces (or if one generalises the dimension, Lorentz spaces).  Someone else's comment also seemed to neglect the fact that the curved manifolds usually dealt with are all locally Euclidean (or Lorentzian, as the case may be) and so the tangent spaces all fall into one of those three categories (with some exceptions).  Um...is the problem that you are assuming "Euclidean" means three dimensions?

Comment: ok yeah, good point (I didn't think about the fact that in general relativity a curved manifold looks locally like a Euclidean or Lorentzian space). Thanks

Comment: I'd personally feel like your answer would be a lot stronger if you wrote "Physicists primarily use..." even given your parenthetical "with some exceptions"

Comment: Well, in Stat Mech non-separable Hilbert spaces arise, but I honestly think that that is a mistake.  Other than that, which other vector spaces do you think are important?